# Xamarin.Android I have installed API version 28 but the project is not building

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

[image]

How to fix it?

In general, my task is to write a function that connects to a Wifi point. It returns True if the password is correct and False otherwise. I had Api version 31 by default, but my code did not work and I decided to put 28, since I have Android 9 on my phone.

```
private async Task<bool> ConnectWifi(string ssid, string pass)
{
    try
    {
        wifi.SetWifiEnabled(true);
        var formssid = $"\"{ssid} \"";
        var formpass = $"\"{pass} \"";
        var config = new WifiConfiguration
        {
            Ssid = formssid,
            PreSharedKey = formpass,
            Priority = 0
        };
        var result = wifi.AddNetworkPrivileged(config);            
        if (result.NetworkId == -1)
            return false;

        wifi.EnableNetwork(result.NetworkId, true);
        return true;
    }
    catch { }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please do not post error message as screen shot. There is usually a simply way to copy the text to clipboard so you can paste it into your question. Please edit your question and do so.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to target the latest android version and set the minimum target version to Android 9 or below, so you can use it on your phone. Anything else doesn't really make sense :/